# How can I get the private key from the eToken by PKCS#11 API?

Tags: c#, c++, openssl, bouncycastle

Currently, I have developed two desktop applications, one is `C++` another is `C#`. The certificates have been stored in `eToken` and marked as non-exportable

I would like to get the private key from eToken through `PKCS#11` library and transform or copy the private key into memory stream or byte array structures, and then pass the key object to the third party cryptography API (`BC/OpenSSL`) for data encryption/decryption.

How can I view or get the private key from the eToken which marked as non-exportable?

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: I think that's the point of non-exportable. its' cryptographically secured, and non exportable - which also means non view-able.

Answer (score 3):

You can't extract a private key marked as non-exportable from your token and that's why is used.  If you need to perform some operation you must send data to the token and then retrieve the result.
At least you could read the certificate inside the USB using the [X509Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx) class (C#)